# Вызов функции с помощью переменных

Tags: c++

Нужно что-то по типу этого. Чтобы из основной части вызывалась функция в зависимости от введенного числа.
Если пользователь вводит 1 - вызывается fun1; а если 2 - fun2; Возможно ли такое или реализовывать все с помощью ветвления?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun1() {
    cout << "fun 1";
}
void fun2() {
    cout << "fun 2";
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter 1|2: ";
    cin >> n;

    fun n();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, массив

```
typedef void (*func)();
func f[] = { nullptr, f1, f2 }

f[n]();  // Дописать проверки!! иначе легко вывалиться за массив или вызвать nullptr
```

Или `map` для разреженного случая.

Примерно так.